Installing Marklogic but get 401 on accessing admin interface
I have installed Marklogic both locally on my pc and also in azure as a VM image. On initially accessing the UI at http://localhost:8001 I can complete the details specifying the admin user/password, but when I complete this I get a 401 unauthorized response.
Can anyone explain what is causing this? I can see no logs directory to get a clue what is causing it.
I have tried clearing the browser cache and reinstalling but to no avail, I just get the same issue.

It shouldn't matter, but which browser? Have you tried testing with an alternate browser, or even curl?

Hi, It seems it is something related to my work laptop, blocking the port 8001. I have tried accessing my azure ML server from another machine and it works fine. Thanks

I have seen reports of issues with Edge logging into that Admin UI root URL with Digest (default authentication for a fresh install).
If you are using Edge, then try http://localhost:8001/default.xqy
Verify which auth schemes are configured, and if digest is included:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#authschemes
Or try using a different browser.
